# "Failed to execute script " pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a python code that I wanted to turn into an exe.
I used pyinstaller with : `pyinstaller --onefile -w script.py`
After it finished making the exe file I double clicked the file but I got "Failed to execute script".

I also tried running it from the cmd but it gives the same fatal error.

Stuff to add:
The code imports a couple of files packages including a python code I made, as well as it makes files referenced to it's location.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

the script has those imports:

```py
import socket
import os
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2
import time
import json
import myFile
```

I ran the code under cmd and it gives this error:

```
  File "script.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PIL import ImageGrab
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

---

Might be unrelated but now that I tried to do `pyinstaller --onefile -w client.py`.
After I ran it windows defender found this inside :
[image]

---

after running it in the terminal in pycharm with :

```
pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import=PIL --hidden-import=Pillow --hidden-import=pynput client.py
```

I get this error (note that i moved it from the dist directory to the main one):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 7, in <module>
    import myFile
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "myFile.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pynput import mouse, keyboard
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "pynput\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 540, in exec_module
  File "pynput\keyboard\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
  File "pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 82, in backend
ImportError
[13364] Failed to execute script client
```

Comment: can you please provide a more complete description? mainly a code sample of script.py and the full error message with traceback would be helpful!

Comment: Make the executable again but this time with the `--debug` option and also without the windowed option so you can see any error messages if any while making the exe and running the script. `pyinstaller --onefile --debug script.py`

Comment: Also move the executable from the dist folder and put it where the script.py was originally, does that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be due to pyinstaller not being able to properly find your dependencies and skipping some packages.

To fix any error like `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'` just add it as a hidden import:

```sh
pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import=PIL -w script.py
```

For the second error this is a known issue with pyinstaller and pynput.
Find [here](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#when-using-a-packager-i-get-an-importerror-on-startup) some explanation.

The TLDR of it seems to be that you need to add `--hidden-import=pynput.mouse._win32 --hidden-import=pynput.keyboard._win32 --hidden-import=pynput._util._win32` and any other sub-packages that give you errors.

Comment: If I want to add the all of the imports mentioned above including the python file I made, I just need to add them all inside hidden-import?

Comment: Yes, you can pass the `--hidden-import=<module>` flag multiple times. You should only add it if a module does not get imported correctly though. Moreover if you have many imports I would suggest using the script.spec file: it is generated automatically but you can then modify it (adding other modules to the hidden_imports list) and the just run `pyinstaller script.spec`

Comment: I tried to add `--hidden-import=PIL` as well as `--hidden-import=Pillow` but it seems as the error doesn't disappear. The full thing : `pyinstaller  --onefile --hidden-import=PIL --hidden-import=Pillow --debug all client.py`

Comment: Are you sure you have PIL installed on your environment? running pyinstaller from a virtual environment sometimes is tricky.

Comment: It seems to change the error now when I used the terminal although now there is a different error on another import, made an edit to the post about it

Comment: @shnap I have edited the answer to cover this part as well. Please if you can next time include the whole error traceback (i believe you left out some rows).

Comment: I left two rows by mistake , added them now

Comment: I seems as tho I get the same error when adding ```--hidden-import=pynput.mouse._win32 --hidden-import=pynput.keyboard._win32 --hidden-import=pynput._util```

Comment: @shnap great! Let me know if the solution works

Comment: @shnap sorry I believe I mistyped, it should be `--hidden-import=pynput.mouse._win32 --hidden-import=pynput.keyboard._win32 --hidden-import=pynput._util._win32`

Comment: I know that you need to avoid comments like "thanks" but thank you for the help man, I appreciate it.